# Segmented control in Navigation bar

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationbar

I need to put segmented control into navigation bar below the title and other buttons. How do I make this? Everything I found so far says you can't increase the height of navigation bar without hacks. Is it even possible?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2fViGVp6nhhOEdJSU0zeWZiS1U/view?pli=1

Comment: r u using storyboard or xib

Comment: I'm using storyboard

Comment: why do you HAVE to use a navigation bar? Its easy to hide navigation bar on a single screen. And add a simple UIView with any content you like right at the top of the screen.

Comment: @SwapnilLuktuke that's a good idea, I guess I'll try that.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you put both of them separately? On top navigation bar and below that UISegmentControl.

Just make sure background for UISegmentControl should be matched and aligned with UINavigation bar.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Will I get a hairline between them? I have to make sure it has no dividers.

Comment: I dont think so if color scheme and background is aligned then no. Give a try because that's the easiest way. You can quickly check this over storyboard or xib update and quick run.